# Performance issue when build cookie expiration date string (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, cookies, string-formatting

I have a c++ code which build an expiration date string for cookie (something like:  `"Thu, 31-Dec-2037 22:00:00 GMT"`) I need it to be 90 from "now". This is my code:

```
    ptime toDay(second_clock::universal_time());
    toDay += days(90);
    date d = toDay.date();
    string dayOfWeek = d.day_of_week().as_short_string();
    int dayOfMonth = d.day();
    string month = d.month().as_short_string();
    int year = (int)toDay.date().year();

    stringstream strs;
    strs << dayOfWeek << ", " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << dayOfMonth << "-" << month << "-" << year << " " << toDay.time_of_day() << " GMT";

    string defaultExpiration = strs.str();
```

The performance of this code is really bad, I would guess it's the `stringstream` use.
If any of you have an alternative which should be faster, I would be happy to test it.
Thanks !

Comment: I don't know what library you are using for the date and time classes, but doesn't it have something akin to [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)? Or maybe you can get a `struct tm` and use `strftime` yourself?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I use `boost::posix_time`. I looked but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Then you have the `to_tm` function which you can use to get a `struct tm` which you can use in `strftime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a sagnificant faster way to do it using [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/), and now it looks like that:

```
ptime today(second_clock::universal_time());
today += days(90);
date d = today.date();
int dayOfMonth = d.day();
int hoursOfDay = today.time_of_day().hours();
int minutesOfDay = today.time_of_day().minutes();

//this function if from "FastFormat"
string defaultExpiration(StringFormatter::Format("{0}, {1}{2}-{3}-{4} {5}{6}:{7}{8}:00 GMT",
    d.day_of_week().as_short_string(),
    dayOfMonth < 10 ? "0" : "",
    dayOfMonth,
    d.month().as_short_string(),
    (int)d.year(),
    hoursOfDay < 10 ? "0" : "",
    hoursOfDay,
    minutesOfDay < 10 ? "0" : "",
    minutesOfDay
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using boost, I think you should give its date_time input/output system a try. What it does is automatically format the date and time in the layout you specify. [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) you can see the boost tutorial on that.

Basically, you need to setup a boost facet for time output in the format you desire - there are many [format specifiers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags) and I am sure you will figure it out.

I am not sure it this would bring a performance improvement but I believe it's worth a try. After all, that's what that subsystem's purpose is - to output dates and times.

Comment: Thanks, that definitally a good place to start. I'll update if the performance was improved or not.

Comment: ): this didn't helped much. the "format" functions and the io support is all using streaming for it.

Comment: Sorry, I hoped that would help.